# How to timestamp application output with perl

Tags: perl, time, io, piping

I have a command line app that gives command line output as it runs. When I write it to a file (ex: app >> log.txt) it all shows up in the text file just like it appeared in terminal. I need to be able to timestamp the output so that if I leave it running I can come back and see when it printed. 
I have tried piping to a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<STDIN>) {
  print time.": $. : $_";
}
```

Using this command:

```
./app | perl timestamp.pl >> test.log 2>&1
```

But the log is empty. I'm sorry I can't be more specific about the application I'm running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suffering from buffering? [Set](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#%24OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH)

```
$| = 1;
```

at the top of your script.

Comment: No, something else is afoot.  `<STDIN>` will block until end-of-line, which, un`chomp`d, would force a flush on the `print` anyway.  Maybe the `./app` isn't generating end-of-lines, but `$|` doesn't speak directly to that.

Comment: @pilcrow: newlines flush a handle attached to a terminal, but not in general

Comment: I tried adding it to the top of my script, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Three stupid questions (1) Are you sure `./app` is producing output? (2) Is `./app` writing to standard output and not standard error? (3) Does `./app` buffer its output? That is, if you run `./app > log`, does `log` only grow in 16K bursts or does it grow slowly?

Comment: That is far neater when written  STDOUT->autoflush(1);  it is much more readable and obvious.

Comment: o.O -> tried out several things today and got it working. I found the only change needed is to add the `$| = 1;`. The odd thing is, I tried that on Friday and it didn't work, but now it does...

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, [@mob's answer solved your immediate problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11365691/100754). However, I would recommend you look into using [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Log::Log4perl) in `easy` mode. It will help you avoid re-inventing the wheel several times, and you'll get easily configurable logging levels for free:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Log::Log4perl qw(:easy);
Log::Log4perl->easy_init($WARN);

while (<>) {
    INFO "$. : $_";
    if ( /easy/ and ($. > 1)) {
        ERROR "$ARGV [$.] - Make easy things harder!";
    }
    if (eof) {
        ALWAYS "Done with $ARGV";
    }
}
```

```
C:\temp> log.pl log.pl
2012/07/07 20:41:57 log.pl [5] - Make easy things harder!
2012/07/07 20:41:57 log.pl [6] - Make easy things harder!
2012/07/07 20:41:57 log.pl [10] - Make easy things harder!
2012/07/07 20:41:57 log.pl [11] - Make easy things harder!
2012/07/07 20:41:57 Done with log.pl
```

Note also:

> While this has been proven to work well familiarizing people with Log::Logperl slowly, effectively avoiding to clobber them over the head with a plethora of different knobs to fiddle with (categories, appenders, levels, layout), the overall mission of Log::Log4perl is to let people use categories right from the start to get used to the concept. So, let's keep this one fairly hidden in the man page (congrats on reading this far :).

Comment: ty for the link! I will probably need this as I expand our logging tools.